# Passing arguments to FFMPEG using subprocess.call()

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I was working through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675529/using-ffmpeg-how-to-do-a-scene-change-detection-with-timecode) to an FFMPEG question and the command works just fine through the Windows 10 command prompt (I've only changed the input and output filenames):

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4  -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo" -f null  - 2> test.txt
```

My Python 3 script gives arguments (as a list) to the `subprocess.call()` function and works fine for a number of basic FFMPEG operations, but not this one!  It seems to be failing at the final `null - 2> test.txt` part, with the following error messages depending on how I split the arguments:

```
[NULL @ 000001c7e556a3c0] [error] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
[error] pipe:: Invalid argument

[error] Unrecognized option '2> test.txt'.
[fatal] Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

[error] Unrecognized option '2>'.
[fatal] Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Here's the basic list of arguments I've been trying:

```
args=['C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe',
      '-i',
      'test.mp4',
      '-filter:v "select=\'gt(scene,0.4)\',showinfo"',
      '-f null',
      '-',
      '2>',
      'test.txt']
```

Plus various permutations combining and splitting the last few elements.

Please could somebody help me with the right syntax for running FFMPEG with these arguments through Python 3?

Many thanks - I just can't see where I'm going wrong :(

Comment: why don't you use a wrapper to ffmpeg instead of calling it externally (which is dangerous). e.g.https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: Thanks Eypros - would like to hear more about why you think it's "dangerous" please? Ultimately doesn't a wrapper have to call ffmpeg externally itself? It's a good thought but here's my reasoning:  1) I'm learning this fresh and after browsing the very wrapper you mentioned, concluded it'll take as long to learn the wrapper syntax as learn the ffmpeg flags themselves; 2) One less dependency, generally good for future-proofing but also I might want to make this project availabile commercially and don't want to have to double check licensing/copyright conditions etc.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't get to the bottom of what was going wrong in my syntax but the following answer provided me with a workaround, essentially using `shell=True` and passing all arguments as a combined string: 
[subprocess call ffmpeg (command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955322/subprocess-call-ffmpeg-command-line)

Here's my updated call:

```
subprocess.call("ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter:v \"select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo\" -f null - 2> output.txt",shell=True)
```

Thanks to the nice people at Pythonista Cafe for finding that one for me :)