# How to compress a video using ffmpeg in python?

Tags: python-3.x, video, ffmpeg, windows-10, video-compression

I made this script for compressing videos in Python 3:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4')
print(result)
```

When I run the above, some error will come up like `System cannot find the file specified` :

```
  result = subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

**Question: How to fix code for correct compressing of videos?**

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes I have tried it and it will show invalid syntax

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: These commands are supposed to be run in the terminal instead of a script, as far as I know

Comment: If you want to use commands like `-i input.mp4` syntax then you need to run `ffmpeg.exe` as a Python **subProcess**. See if this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25964123/2057709) helps you (replace their `+str(out_movie),` with your `+'output.mp4',`)

Comment: There is a library ffmpeg (https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/). API reference https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/

Comment: @yuRa It is showing a error like   input  is invalid syntax

Comment: thanks @VC.One. but it is showing -i is not defined

Comment: Show us your `subprocess.call` line. PS: You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64421177/edit) button (under the tags) to add new info. Show simple and testable code for us to recreate your same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Nearly correct! It looks like the only module you need is subprocess. You should run your command in `run()` function. Try this:

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4')
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks but it is showing an error like this     ``` result = subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified```

Comment: It looks like you don't have ffmpeg installed. Follow this! http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

Comment: @ 武状元  I have installed ffmpeg-python using pip install python-ffmpeg

Comment: Not finished! You need to install FFmpeg. ffmpeg-python is just a Python wrapper for FFmpeg.

Comment: Also I have installed ffmpeg.exe file

Comment: Type `ffmpeg` in windows shell. How it says?

Comment: Ok I will try  @武状元