# How can I add chapters to .mp4 files using a python script?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, metadata, mp4, video-processing

Is there an easy way to add chapters (i.e.: sections with titles) to .mp4 files using a python script?

For example, the script could process a 3-minutes video and label the first minute as "Beginning", the second minute as "Middle", and the last minute as "End".

The only solution ([link](https://ikyle.me/blog/2020/add-mp4-chapters-ffmpeg)) I stumbled upon so far involves using a ffmpeg command on the command line to extract the original ffmetadata from the video file before appending the chapters to it and updating the video with it.

However, I would like the process to be automated using a python script (instead of having to use the command line each time I have to process a video).

Comment: Running the program via the command line to achieve your objective is already a form of automation, so what is your question? If it's a recommendation to find a library in Python to do this, I am afraid that is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Not really, I would like to run that command within a larger python program that processes video files. I just want to find a way to do so without having to go through the command line separately.

Comment: You might be looking for a way to [run ffmpeg through Python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955322/subprocess-call-ffmpeg-command-line).

Comment: I tried doing so but it tells me that it doesn't recognize ffmpeg as a command for some reason, although I did import it to my pycharm virtual environment. @metatoaster

Comment: You may need to provide the full path to the `ffmpeg` executable.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue using subprocess.call(command, shell=True) function after updating my path variable. The 'shell=True' argument allowed me to process the command as a regular shell command, and updating the path variable made ffmpeg recognizable. I initially thought I had to use the ffmpeg-python module but it's easier to do it this way. Thank you @metatoaster for your help!

Comment: Using `shell=True` may be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, I was able to achieve what I wanted using the subprocess.call(command, shell=True) function after updating my path variable.

The 'shell=True' argument allowed me to process the command as a regular shell command ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197883/how-to-use-ffmpeg-in-a-python-function)), and updating the path variable made ffmpeg recognizable.

I didn't have to use ffmpeg-python module after all since it was easier to use the ffmpeg ([downloaded from here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)) command on shell that worked fine initially.